# Ready made docker-compose.yml with Wireguard client and Traefik router to expose Proxmox home server to internet

Tags: proxmox, tunneling, wireguard, traefik

I want to expose web services from Docker container running in LXC and from virtual machines to internet through Traefik router, single Wireguard tunnel and VPS. I also want to use same tunnel for SSH for controlling Proxmox and VMs and containers over internet.

I already have Docker container on VPS running Wireguard server. I want to run all client configuration inside a Docker container in LXC in Proxmox.

I am sure this is already done before, do you know some existing repository with `docker-compose.yml` and Wireguard client and Traefik and SSH with additional configuration code and tutorial? I would prefer that as much as possible configuration is scripted as code and easily deployable and removable.

Any links to proven repositories and tutorials are appreciated.

Comment: Home questions are off topic. Requests for external resources are off topic.